# Отличие существительного от подлежащего

Tags: существительные, подлежащее

Отличие существительного от подлежащего с примерами хочу. Если можно, то подробно, мне очень тяжело понять, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Эту тему можно представить в игровой форме, которую мы назовем **"актеры и роли".** Пьесой, разумеется, будет предложение.

Актеры — это **части речи**: существительное, прилагательное, глагол, местоимение, наречие.

Роли — это **члены предложения**. Главные члены — **подлежащее и сказуемое,** второстепенные члены —  дополнение, определение и обстоятельство.

**Подлежащее обозначает действующий предмет**, а сказуемое называет действие.

**На роль подлежащего чаще всего выбирают существительное**, так как оно  как раз и обозначает предмет. Глагол обозначает действие.

Вот предложение: **На площадке дети играют в мяч.**

В нем **три существительных**, и у всех разные роли. Дети (**именительный падеж**) — это подлежащее (кто?), в мяч (винительный падеж) — дополнение (во что?), на площадке (предложный падеж) — обстоятельство (на чём? где?).

Но на роль подлежащего можно выбрать не только существительное, но и, к примеру, личное местоимение: ***Они играют в мяч***.

Иногда даже глагол  (неопределенная форма) может стать подлежащим, а наречие — сказуемым: ***Играть было весело.***

Answer (score 2):

Это термины разного уровня языка.

Существительное как часть речи изучает морфология, указывая его основное значение, постоянные и непостоянные признаки.

Подлежащее - единица синтаксиса. При разборе предложения мы указываем, какую роль в предложении играет существительное, а оно может быть подлежащим (главным членом предложения, отвечающим на вопрос кто? что?), или дополнением (отвечает на вопросы косвенных падежей), или несогласованным определением, или обстоятельством.

*Отговорила роща золотая.*

(Что?) роща - **существительное**, в предложении является **подлежащим**.

*Я любовался лесом.*

(Чем?) лесом - существительное, в предложении является дополнением.

*Я гулял в лесу.*

(Гулял где? в чём?) в лесу - существительное с предлогом, в предложении является обстоятельством места.